# Free PDF Printer on remote machine

Tags: pdf, printing, software-rec, print-to-pdf

I need a free, spy and addware free, pdf print driver for windows.

My only additional requirement is that it needs to run fine via Remote Desktop.

There are tons on the internet, but it is hard to know which ones print extra stuff on the document (Like "Buy the full version for more features").

Answer (score 6):

I use [Cute PDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/) but another admin at my company uses [PrimoPDF](http://www.primopdf.com/index.aspx). I can confirm that both work fine when redirected over RDP.

EDIT: Oh, and they don't print any other nonsense on the documents!

Comment: I use and like Cute PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the RDP part, but free and spyware free.
[bullzip](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php)

Answer (score 0):

Also (like user `skub` in another answer to this question) not sure about RDP for this software, but [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) is good (at least the older ones were, I have not used it for a little while now so I'm not sure aboout the newest ones). But [I have heard that it installs some possibly "malicious" software by default](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFCreator#Inclusion_of_malware) in the newer versions, so, either use an older version (the Wikipedia page currently says that the possibly not such good software started to be included with version 0.9.7), or install carefully (possibly looking through all installation options).